# var is public final by default but, re-intianlizable

Tags: kotlin

I'm new to learn about KOTLIN, I found that **`public final`** is there by default for classes & variables.

but I'm surprised how can final variable value be changed?

```
public final var x = 4

x = 5
```

can anyone clarify that for me, please?

Comment: Immutable variables should be created using val keyword: `val x = 4`. Have a look at: https://fabiomsr.github.io/from-java-to-kotlin/index.html for understanding Kotlin syntax using java examples. [`final`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/keyword-reference.html) keyword is used to block the inheritence.

Comment: ok thanks, but i was shocked that public final is default for var too

Comment: It is not final in the JVM bytecode, you can goto `Tools` -> `Kotlin` -> `Show Kotlin bytecode` -> `Decompile to Java` to check yourself. Final are different keyword in both languages.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`final` keyword is strictly used for [inheritance](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#overriding-properties).

If you want immutable property you use `val` instead of `var`.

By default everything is `final` so it cannot be inherited or overriden. If you don't want something to be `final` you have to explicitly mark it as `open`:

```
open class Foo {
    var x = 5
}

class Foo2 : Foo() {
    override var x = 7  // error : 'x' in 'Foo' is final and cannot be overridden
}

open class Bar {
    open var x = 5
}

class Bar2 : Bar() {
    override var x = 8  // ok
}

open class Bar3 : Bar() {
    final override var x = 9  // ok, final prevents further overrides
}

class Bar3Child : Bar3() {
    override var x = 10  // error : 'x' in 'Bar3' is final and cannot be overridden
}
```

Comment: I know about Val, but, then do you mean that the final keyword now not the same as in java?

Comment: @MoustafaEL-Saghier it's similar as far as class and method inheritance goes (where in java everything is "open" by default). When you consider how properties work in Kotlin (they're essentially just a getter & setter which may or may not generate an internal backing field) it does make sense since `final` won't allow you to override getter / setter methods.

Answer (score 3):

You are mixing up variables and properties.

In Java, there are member field variables and there are local variables (inside functions). In Kotlin, variables only appear inside functions and constructors. There are no member fields (except inside custom property getters and setters), only properties.

In Java, `final` for any type of variable means you cannot change its value, but `final` for a method means you cannot override it.

In Kotlin, local variables (variables in functions) can have the same behavior as a Java `final` variable by marking them as `val` instead of `var`.

A Kotlin property is like a method (or pair of methods). Marking it `final` means you can't override it. Marking it as `val` means it has no setter, but this doesn't necessarily mean it is immutable, because you could choose to write a custom getter for it that returns a different value every time. The behavior equivalent to a Java `final` member field variable would be a `val` property with no custom getter function.

Kotlin defaults to `final` for classes, functions, and properties because it leads to more robust design. Since `final` is default and properties allow you to more easily encapsulate behavior of the class, it is more sensible for `public` to be the default scope for classes and properties. And the equivalent of the Java Default scope doesn't even exist in Kotlin.